# Add item to listbox and then send email to target recipient

Tags: c#, listbox, email-validation

Good day guys, i'm a semi-intermediate here in c#, i need a help regarding on my codes about the said title, actually it does not work with my implemented code. but here's the scenario, if the list box item is added, the said added target would be send an email to the specific target email address within my declared second/s.

here are my codes and Procedures.

1.) Procedure for statmessage:

public void statmessage()

```
    {
        string connstr = "server = ***.***.***.***; database = dbname; UID = ****; password = ****;";
        SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        string sqlstr = "select a.or_date, a.TransactionNo , a.email, a.bemail from vw_forEmailSending a where a.or_date between '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2500-12-31 00:00:00.000' order by or_date asc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, dbconn);

        dbconn.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {

               listBox1.Items.Add(new EItem(rdr.GetSqlDateTime(0) + " - " + "Transaction No.: " + rdr.GetString(1) + " has been submitted successfully all the details at " + rdr.GetString(2) + "."));


            lblcount.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;



        }

        rdr.Close();
        dbconn.Close();
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
        listBox1.Refresh();

    }
```

2.)In the form:

private int counter;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        counter = 100;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

3.)Actually, I used timer for this and here is the tick procedure code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statmessage();

        int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count + 1;

      if (i < 1)
        {
            var exp = (EItem)listBox1.Items[i];
            var timeVisible = DateTime.Now - exp.Added;
            if (timeVisible.TotalSeconds > 5)
                if (counter == 100)
                {

                SendMessage();
                counter = counter - 1;
                ++i;
                }
                else if (counter <= 0)
                {

                statmessage();
                }

        }

    }
```

- Your feedback is highly appreciated and will help to improve the said concern, Thank you very much

Comment: what's your actual question?      things like ```
        int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count + 1;

      if (i < 1)``` are weird, as the if will never happen, but I'm not quite sure what you are really asking?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, about timer_tick procedure code. the declared seconds for the email in the target added transaction on the list box doesn't work. how to correct those said syntax?

Comment: your if condition can never work, it's saying i less than 1,  the list at minimum can be zero, but then you add 1 to it,  so it will never meet the condition of being less than 1

Comment: Thank you for the advice mate, actually i change my if condition to (i < 0) but i won't work also.  can you please state an example code or improve the timer1_Tick procedure, Thanks again.

Comment: you want i > 0    if do i < 0  then i has to be -1 or less......

Answer (score 0):

mate, i will show my changes of the code and please re-write it if there's something wrong, thank you..

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            statmessage();
            int i = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count + 1;
            do
            {
                var exp = (EItem)listBox1.Items[i];
                var timeVisible = DateTime.Now - exp.Added;
                if (timeVisible.TotalSeconds > 5)
                    if (counter == 100)
                    {
                        SendMessage();
                        counter = counter - 1;
                        ++i;
                    }
                    else if (counter